# probability of a collection of uniform random variables conditioned on the max value

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, bayesian

Just come across this question:

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n)$ be i.i.d. according to a uniform
distribution $U(0, θ)$ for some $θ > 0$. Let
$x = (x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n)$ denote a particular realization of  $X$. 
Let $T(x) = \max(x_1, . . . , x_n)$.

Show that $p(X = x | T(x) = t)$
doesn’t depend on $\theta$, where now $t ∈ R$ is some fixed real satisfying $0 < t < θ$.

**My Question:**

But I think, given $T(x) = t$, since $X$ is ***continuous*** random variable, there are still infinitely many $X=x$ that may satisfy $\max(x_1, . . . , x_n)=t$, thus $p(X = x | T(x) = t)$ for any given $x$ should be **zero**?

Answer (score 1):

> **My Question:**
>
> But I think, given $T(x) = t$, since $X$ is ***continuous*** random variable, there are still infinitely many $X=x$ that may satisfy $\max(x_1, . . . , x_n)=t$, thus $p(X = x \mid T(x) = t)$ for any given $x$ should be **zero**?

Indeed the probability mass will be zero; however to be sensible, the problem should be interpreted to be looking for a probability *density* function, not a probability mass function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  If it's to be interpreted as density function, then why in the parenthesis, it's $X=x$ which is an event, but not a variable $x$?

Comment: @ranky Well, the conditional probability density of random vector $X$ at values $x$ when given the maximum member of $X$ is $t$, *would* be more conventionally written as $f_{ X \mid T(X)=t }( x )$, or similar, but the notation of $p( X=x \mid T(X)=t )$ is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. To get the conditional density, should we proceed like $p(X=x|T(X)=t) = \frac{p(X=x,T(X)=t)}{p(T(X)=t)}$? If so, how do we get the joint density in the numerator, since X and T(X) are not independent?